# Migrating NSPersistentStore from application sandbox to shared group container

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, watchkit

I am trying to move my NSPersistentStore from my app's sandbox to a shared group container so I can access CoreData from my WatchKit extension. I am currently using Core Data with iCloud and want to move the users data to the shared group container. Currently I am creating the NSPersistentStoreCoordinator as follows:

```
if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

NSURL *url = [self storeURL]; // app's Documents directory
NSError *error = nil;
__persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:url options:[self iCloudPersistentStoreOptions] error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Error adding persistent store: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

// rest of setup

return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

I've already setup the shared group container in my app target and WatchKit extension target and can get the NSURL for the new store location using `- (NSURL *)containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:(NSString *)groupIdentifier`.

How can I check whether I need to migrate or that I've already migrated so I don't attempt to migrate multiple times?  Initially I was thinking of something like this, but this doesn't work as the old store URL doesn't exist

```
if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

NSURL *newURL = [self newStoreURL]; // shared group container
NSURL *oldURL = [self oldStoreURL]; // app's Documents directory

__persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:newURL.path] && [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:oldURL.path]) {
    NSLog(@"performing migration...");
    NSPersistentStore *oldStore = [__persistentStoreCoordinator persistentStoreForURL:oldURL];
    NSError *migrateError = nil;
    NSPersistentStore *newStore = [__persistentStoreCoordinator migratePersistentStore:oldStore toURL:newURL options:[self iCloudPersistentStoreOptions] withType:NSSQLiteStoreType error:&migrateError];
    if (!newStore) {
        NSLog(@"Error migrating store: %@", [migrateError localizedDescription]);
    }
}

// rest of setup

return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, it looks like you're pretty much there if the migration logic you posted is working. What it seems you are missing is an `else if` to handle the case where you don't have a persistent store. The following should handle that case.

```
if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

NSURL *newURL = [self newStoreURL]; // shared group container
NSURL *oldURL = [self oldStoreURL]; // app's Documents directory

__persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:newURL.path] && [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:oldURL.path]) {
    NSLog(@"performing migration...");
    NSPersistentStore *oldStore = [__persistentStoreCoordinator persistentStoreForURL:oldURL];
    NSError *migrateError = nil;
    NSPersistentStore *newStore = [__persistentStoreCoordinator migratePersistentStore:oldStore toURL:newURL options:[self iCloudPersistentStoreOptions] withType:NSSQLiteStoreType error:&migrateError];
    if (!newStore) {
        NSLog(@"Error migrating store: %@", [migrateError localizedDescription]);
    }
} else if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:newURL.path]) {
    if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:newURL options:[self iCloudPersistentStoreOptions] error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Error adding persistent store: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}

// rest of setup

return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

Comment: The problem is that with existing installs (users who are upgrading and already have data), [NSFileManager fileExistsAtPath:oldURL.path] returns false for some reason.

Comment: The actual store file in my case is actually in the Documents/CoreDataUbiquitySupport/<device>/<app_id>/local/store directory which is why [NSFileManager fileExistsAtPath:oldURL.path] is returning false